# how to correctly use Firebase.Firestore.FieldValue.ServerTimestamp in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

Currently, I was working on a Unity project and using Firestone as my database.
now i facing a problem is when i create a document in firestone i want to add the time of creation also.
i was using the code
db.Collection("Challenges").Document(addedDocRef.Id).UpdateAsync("TimeCreated", Firebase.Firestore.FieldValue.ServerTimestamp);

but it always update the same time in firestone.

[image]

every document get same timestemp, can anyone teach me how to solve this issue?

Comment: sorry, this is my first time using stackoverload, i still not familiar with this.

Answer (score 0):

The [FieldValue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/firestore/field-value) properties are [sentinel values](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) in this case to be understood as **dummy values** that are supposed to be filled in by "someone".

I don't know how Firebase works exactly and who is supposed to fill this in but what you get basically equals [`DateTime.UnixEpoch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.unixepoch) the default uninitialized system time (+ 7:30 timeszone shift). It might have to be configured accordingly somewhere before it works correctly.

You could instead simply pass in your own timestamp using e.g. [`DateTime.Now`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now#System_DateTime_Now)